# How can I handling Javascript Object Array in Spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, json, spring

## here is my request object (js) ...

```
{
    replace : [ {
        original : "A"
        , replace : "B"
        , reason : "bbb"
    }, {
        original : "C"
        , replace : "D"
        , reason : "ddd"
    } ]
    , form : {
        reasonDetail : "just kidding..."
        , name : "jane"
        , cell : "123-4567-8910"
        , zipcode : "12345"
    }
}
```

replace is javascript array
form is javascript object


I want to handling these in spring mvc
My spring code is here...

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping( "/replaceSubmit" )
public String replaceSubmit(
    @RequestParam( "replace" ) List<Map<String, Object> replace
    , @RequestParam( "form" ) Map<String, Object> form ) {

    LOG.debug( replace ) ;
    // spring does not handle replace data ...  


    ....
}
```

but these code was working
spring is can handle
but key of params is stranged. parse to HARD !!

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping( "/replaceSubmit" )
public String replaceSubmit(
    @RequestParam Map<String, Object> params ) {

    LOG.debug( params ) ;

    ....
}
```

e.g.
 
replace[0][original] = ...
replace[0][replace] = ...
replace[0][reason] = ...
replace[1][original] = ...
replace[1][replace] = ...
replace[1][reason] = ...
form[reasonDetail] = ...
form[name] = ...
form[cell] = ...
form[zipcode] = ...


HELP ME !!

I wrote parsing code... this is my best.

```
~~~ @RequestParam Map<String, String> params) ~~~
Iterator<String> ki = params.keySet().iterator() ;
// replace pattern
Pattern pr = Pattern.compile( "^*\\[(.)\\]\\[(.*?)\\]" ) ;
// form pattern
Pattern pf = Pattern.compile( "^*\\[(.*?)\\]" ) ;
Matcher mr, mf ;
int rc = 0 ;
List<Map<String, String>> replaceList = new ArrayList() ;
Map<String, String> replace = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
Map<String, String> form = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
while( ki.hasNext() ) {
    String Key = ki.next() ;
    mr = pr.matcher( Key ) ;
    mf = pf.matcher( Key ) ;
    if( mr.find() ) {
        int kipr1 = Integer.parseInt( mr.group( 1 ) ) ;
        String kipr2 = mr.group( 2 ) ;
        if( rc < kipr1 ) {
            rc = kipr1 ;
            replace = new HashMap<String, String>() ;
        }
        replace.put( kipr2, params.get( Key ) ) ;
        if( replaceList.size() == kipr1 + 1 ) {
            replaceList.set( kipr1, replace ) ;
        } else {
            replaceList.add( kipr1, replace ) ;
        }
    } else if( mf.find() ) {
        String kipf = mf.group( 1 ) ;
        form.put( kipf, params.get( Key ) ) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Annotation @RequestBody for getting data from the Request in your controller. It will be lot easier to do it with the Request body. Make a POJO that matches the request type and then place it in your Controller.

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public void getData(@RequestBody YourClassName YourClassObject)
{
#Now you can just access all the values from the class object directly
}
```